# How to index and search an ENUM type with Hibernate-Search

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search, enumerated

I am working in a Spring, Jpa, Hibernate-Search, Lucene application. I want to index a JPA entity which has a ENUM property and use Lucene to search on that. Every element in my ENUM has a int value.

I put the @Field annotation on the property, but is not working. In the database the field is being stored as an Integer.

```
@Field
@Enumerated
private STATUS status = STATUS.FIRST;
```

Now I want to use Lucene for search using this field

```
//lucene query to search by that enum field 
queryStatus.should(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("status").matching(1).createQuery());
```

I cannot change the enum storage to string type because it has other queries working and using this enum propoerty as an integer and I do not know how to index and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I was able to solve the issue, when searching instead of use the int value, I convert it to the explicit enum.

```
queryStatus.should(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("status").matching(MyClass.STATUS.fromValue(status)).createQuery());
```

That solved my issue.